# Azure Error Referencing Local Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I've got a web app deployed on Azure and I'm getting an error on the Azure deployment that shows the reference to a class library in the same solution.

But the error message shows a file path on my local:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
**XXX.Domain.Concrete.EFBusinessRepository.PrepForConversionToHtml(XXX x) in c:\dev\repos\Jeff\ClassLibrary\Concrete\EFBusinessRepository.cs:1280**

and not one more typical to Azure:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
**XXX.Domain.Concrete.EFBusinessRepository.PrepForConversionToHtml(XXX x) in 
E:\sitesroot\0\bin.....**

Am I overreacting on this?  It just seems dumb that it's showing a path on my local.  I'm in the midst of tracking down all of the errors of a new Azure deployment, so apologies if this is expected behavior.

Comment: Are your pdbs deployed too?

Comment: @allen yea, it looks like it.  I assume that that is problematic?  Is deleting them off of the Azure server sufficient?

Comment: If you have moved to retail then your should. The pdbs help with debug information in case of failures where you would get richer stack traces etc which I guess you dont need when you have deployed to production. Your logging infra should be sufficient for this.

Comment: Yep, deleting the pdbs removed the file path reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in the resolution as answer here.

The pdb files contain additional debug information wrt your binaries. Any failures that show up on a machine with pdbs deployed will show a richer stack information referring back to the source code files with line numbers etc. Deleting out the pdbs will resolve your issue. Plus you ideally should not be deploying pdbs with your retail product bits unless you are actively debugging something in production.